Is the comma after "practices" in that sentence correct?
A lot of people care about the environment, and a lot don’t. Which side are you? It’s your practices that tell. For those who don’t, there must be a way to make them aware of their bad practices, and how to change them.
Should there be a comma after "practices" in the last sentence?

'And how to change them' is the phrase that relates to 'bad practices'  and comma is used to connect 2 separate sentences. So there should be no comma after "practices" in the last sentence

I'd use a dash to distinguish the different types of separators.

In your sentence, the phrase "and how to change them" is part of the same clause as "make them aware of their bad practices." A comma should not be added between them.
Furthermore, using a comma there would create a separation between "make them aware of their bad practices" and "how to change them," which are closely related and should be read together without pause.
https://www.scribbr.com/commas/comma-before-or-after-and/ has more details and examples!
